# Scala covariance losing type constraints

Tags: scala, covariance, type-parameter, implicits

I wonder how can I preserve my type constraints while trying to workaround over 'Covariant type parameter in a wrong position problem' situation. Here is the code:

```
trait Converter[SourceType, +JobType <: ConverterJobType[SourceType]] {
   def convert[JT >: JobType](job: JT):String = job.someMethodFromJobType()// method is not accessible here. I would like to use JobType but actually job is treated like type Any.
}

object Converter{
   implicit object CSVConverter extends Converter[CSV, CSVConverterJobType]{
     def converter....
   }
 }
```

I need covariance so that my implicit object could be looked up.

```
 case class CSVConverterJobType(...) extends ConverterJobType[SourceType]

 object Application {

    def process[T](job: List[T])(implicit 
       converter:Converter[T,ConverterJobType[T]]) = {...}

    val list:List[CSV] = ...
    process(list)

 }
```

In order to  `process` method to be able to find implicit.... I need to make second type parameter covariant. But then I'm not able to use actual type information in `convert` method.

Any idea how to overcome this?

Answer (score 2):

`JT` needs to be `<: JobType` in order for `job.someMethodFromJobType()` to work. If `JT` is an arbitrary supertype of `JobType` then it doesn't have a `someMethodFromJobType()` method.

You should convert the second type argument to a type member, especially if there is only one `JobType` per `SourceType` (if not, the implicit search won't work anyway as it won't know which `JobType` to choose):

```
trait Converter[SourceType] {
  type JobType <: ConverterJobType[SourceType]
  def convert...
}

object Converter{
  implicit object CSVConverter extends Converter[CSV]{
    type JobType = CSVConverterJobType
    def convert....
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Ziyang Liu. I introduced JT type because in case  of I'm using covariance for second type parameter  I can't use this type for method's parameter anymore( function input parameter is contrvariant). Yes..you are right...it wouldn't be able to resolve such an ambiguity in case of multiple JobType per SourceType.  I was trying to use type members... and maybe it is easier to use for my case because basically these types are paired...CSV goes with CSVConverterJobType and so on. But I was shifted tow more complicated solution. But your answer helps me clarify my case. Tnx!

Comment: Today I've tried to use type member for JobType and it's the same problem.... compiler treat it like covariant type and therefore I still can't use it in my method's parameter list.

Comment: I'm thinking of using Magnet pattern for this. Will let anyone know about results. But still open for suggestion how to make it works through type constraints.

Comment: You should be able to use type member in a parameter list. It will be helpful if you can update your question to include exactly what you tried to do.

Comment: Actually it is in my question. I need to call method `someMethodFromJobType` on a job.  For that I need to pass job into convert method. When we use type member `type JobType <:  ConverterJobType[SourceType]`  it implicitly makes JobType convariant( only in case when type constraint is a generic type). And that is why I can't pass it into method's parameter list.